# C++ "Could not convert 'class instance' from 'Class (*)()' to 'Class'"

Tags: c++, class, g++

I am writing a class in c++ which is throwing the above error when compiling with g++ on Debian.  I think the problem may be in a custom data structure I used, but I'm not sure and haven't been able to find any other questions on this particular error.

Here's the main class:

```
//3-Space Object tests

#include <iostream>
#include "obj3.h"
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace Eigen;

void print_obj_attributes(Obj3 obj)
{
std::cout << obj.get_owner() << std::endl;
...
std::cout << obj.get_bounding_box() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
//Set up some objects
Obj3 obj2 ();

//Print out the object attributes to test the getters and initializers

std::cout << "Object 2" << std::endl;
print_obj_attributes(obj2);
```

The obj3.h file (and it's companion cpp file) both compile correctly with g++.  I have removed some elements and am not including the cpp file to preserve space.
    #ifndef OBJ3_H
    #define OBJ3_H

```
#include <string>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include "list.h"

class Obj3
{
    private:
            //String Attributes
            std::string name;
            ...

            //Float Matrices for location, rotation, & scaling
            Eigen::Vector3f location;
            ...

            //Private constructor for internal matrices
            void initialize_matrices();
            void initialize_buffers();

            //A list of scenes
            List <std::string> scene_list;

    public:
            //Constructor
            Obj3() {initialize_matrices(); owner=""; ...}
            //Methods for controlling scene list

            //Get a scene
            std::string get_scene(int index){return scene_list.get(index);}

            //Add a scene
            bool add_scene(std::string scene_id){scene_list.append(scene_id);return true;}

            //Remove a scene
            bool remove_scene(int index){scene_list.remove(index); return true;}

            //Getters & Setters for string attributes

            //Set the name
            bool set_name(std::string new_name, std::string device_id){name=new_name; return true;}
            //Getter
            std::string get_owner() {return owner;}
            ...
```

There are some additional methods that I don't think are causing any issues.  Below is the List.h file which I think is the problem:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

template <class T>
class List
{
  T *int_array;
  int cur_int_array_size;
  int current_length;
  void extend_array()
{
  int cur_len = 0;
  int n=0;
  cur_len = cur_int_array_size;
  T *new_array = new int[cur_len+10];
  for (n=0;n<cur_int_array_size;n++)
  { 
    new_array[n] = int_array[n];
  }
  delete int_array;
  int_array = new_array;
  cur_int_array_size=cur_int_array_size+10;
}
  public:
    List() {current_length=0;cur_int_array_size=10;int_array=new int[10];}
    ~List() {delete int_array;}
    T get (int index) {return int_array[index];}
    void append (T obj) {if (current_length == cur_int_array_size) {extend_array();} int_array[current_length+1] = obj; current_length++;}
    void insert (int index, T obj) {if (current_length == cur_int_array_size) {extend_array();} int_array[index] = obj; current_length++;}
    void remove (int index) {int i=index;for (i=index; i < cur_int_array_size - 1; i++) {int_array[i] = int_array[i+1];}current_length--;}
    int length () {return current_length;}
};
#endif
```

The cpp file for this is just an include statement for the list.h file.

The List file compiles successfully with:

```
g++ -c -o list.o list.cpp
```

The Obj3 file compiles successfully with:

```
g++ -c -o obj3.o obj3.cpp
```

I'm trying to compile the Obj3 test (Main module) with:

```
g++ -c -o obj3_test.o obj3_test.cpp
```

Which is when I get the error:

```
 in function 'int main()':
 could not convert ‘obj2’ from ‘Obj3 (*)()’ to ‘Obj3’
```

After this, the final step should be to compile the test with:

```
g++ -o obj_test list.o obj3.o obj3_test.o
```

Comment: `Obj3 obj2 ();` doesn't do what you think it does. Start by losing the parens. You may find [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34404267/1322972) to a similar question helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a default-constructed instance of `Obj3`, write

```
Obj3 obj2;
```

instead of

```
Obj3 obj2 ();
```

The latter declares a function returning an object of type `Obj3`.